# How do I replace an old expired iOS app with a new app that I built from the ground up?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-developer

I have what I believe to be a pretty unique situation and I can't seem to find a solution online.  The problem timeline:

- 4 years ago I paid a developer to build/upload an app to the iOS App Store for me under my own developer account.
- Over the years it became outdated and this April it was kicked out of the App Store
- I took some online courses this year and rebuilt the app from the ground up.
- I would like to post my rebuilt version to the App Store - completely fresh like it's a brand new app (because it basically is)

A couple more things to consider...

- I used Swift vs the original Objective-C that the developer used.
- I used UserDefaults instead of what appears to be iCloud. (the dev account seems to be littered with permissions for things I don't intend to use - so advice on how to get rid of all of the weird stuff I don't use would be helpful, too)
- I also have a different but similar bundle identifier (it replaces "RandomRuby" with "Random-Ruby") that Apple's App ID registration system seems to not like.
- The level content and game play are the same - but I have no idea how to figure out what level the previous users were on. (which I'm ok with if it's ethical to make people start over).
- It had In-App purchases (they could purchase consumable "Rubies" to use for hints and there was an "Ad Free" upgrade option.  The new app doesn't use ads - it just has consumable "Rubies" for monetization). I have no plan to add ads back in - so I imagine a complete reset would be ok here, too?  Again - is that ethical?

With all of this context - my question is...

How do I upload a completely-rebuilt-from-scratch app with the exact same name from the exact same company as an expired app through the iOS Developer system?  Is this even possible?  I'm having a hard time figuring out where to start.  I can't even get past creating an App ID.

Comment: Do you want existing users of your old app to see this new app as an update to their existing app or should this be a new app for everyone?

Comment: Well you might want to make an app update?

Comment: @rmaddy - new to everyone.  I want it to be a complete refresh as though the old one never existed.  I'd love for this to be reflected everywhere in my dev account / iTunesConnect, too if possible.  I just want my own stuff in there and not the work that I had those other devs do.

Comment: @KarloA.López - I'd prefer to not have to do it as an update.  I'm open to it - but I no longer use iCloud in the app, I don't have any of the same code at all, I have no way of retrieving old purchases (so I'm not even sure how I'd approach handling that).  There seem to be a lot of barriers to going the "app update" route.

Comment: @LeviLais If you want to create a whole new app then just do that. Create a new app id, new bundle id, etc. Forget the other app existed.

Comment: @rmaddy when I try to delete the app in iTunesConnect, it says that I can never use that name again if I delete it.  Do you know a way around this outside of having to choose a different name?

Comment: Nope, you need to use a different name. But the difference can be a single character. No need to delete the old app either.

Answer (score 1):

To update **an existing app** in **your Apple Developer account** you only need to use the same **BUNDLE ID** (e.g. com.apple.keynote) in your Xcode project and a higher version/build number. Everything else is not relevant.

Comment: If you read the comments you will see that the goal is to create a new app, not an update to an existing app.

Comment: Okay then simply set it up as a new app, what’s the issue? Remove the old from sale. You can’t use the old app name. If you want to use it you have to update the old app and change the name for it. As it’s a new app all the other information you provided are irrelevant

Answer (score -1):

Your previous iOS APP is bounded with the Apple Developer account when it was submitted. And the APP name is unique, just like anyone else may not create another app named 'Facebook'.

So, if the Apple Developer account was not yours, you are in trouble. You need to ask the previous programmer to transfer the APP to you.
If the Apple Developer account was merely expired, and you can prove that the account belongs to you, I guess you can contact Apple Support for help.